# Echo a script tag from LinkedIn

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api

Is there a way to echo these scripts in their complete form via php echo?

`<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">api_key: 11111 </script> <script type="IN/Apply" data-companyid="111111" data-jobtitle="Sr. Software Support Programmer/Analyst" data-joblocation="atlanta" data-email="script@gmail.com"></script>`

These scripts are generated from  a LinkedIn tool, and I would like for the client to be able to copy, then paste into a custom field in Wordpress.

When I try to echo this field, it writes to the page.

Comment: Thx. It makes me wait 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html_entity_decode()` is what I needed http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [PHP function htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

```
echo htmlentities('<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">api_key: 11111 </script> <script type="IN/Apply" data-companyid="111111" data-jobtitle="Sr. Software Support Programmer/Analyst" data-joblocation="atlanta" data-email="script@gmail.com"></script>');
```

Comment: Actually, I need to do the opposite. html_entity_decode()works for me.